# Limiting my populate view to one set of values from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to limit my populateView to only display one set of values which is requested from Chat.class

When i remove the Query, my android app displays the values in a list as they come from firebase.

I just want one value to come in and the old one to be removed when the new one comes in.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Chat msg = new Chat(23 , 66); // Writing to firebase to test values coming back
    ref.push().setValue(msg);

    DatabaseReference chatRef = ref.child("chat_messages");
    Query recentMessages = chatRef.limitToLast(1);

    FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this,
            Chat.class,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            recentMessages) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("Temp: " + String.valueOf(chatMessage.getTemp()));
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText("Humitity: " + String.valueOf(chatMessage.getHumi()));

        }
    };
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I also have an event listener in place which dosnt seem to be doing anything, as the textView works better for me.

```
ref.limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Chat msg = msgSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            Log.i("Chat", msg.getTemp()+": " +msg.getHumi());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("Chat", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

My constructor

```
 public Chat(float Humi, float Temp) {
    mHumi = Humi;
    mTemp = Temp;
}
```

Comment: The `recentMessages` query will contain at most one message: the most recent one (according to key). What problem are you seeing?

Comment: There is nothing displayed in the Listview